# Floating point error in ULPs (units in the last place)

Tags: floating-point, precision

This question is based on the paper [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/551.jvn.fall01/goldberg.pdf) by David Goldberg. In the section 1.2 Relative Error and Ulps (page number 8), the paper gives an equation to calculate error in, ULP (units in the last place):

```
| d.d…d - (z/(β^e)) | β^(p-1)
```

Where `d.d…d * (β^e)` is the floating point representation of the number `z` and, `β` and `p` are the base and precision of the representation.

Later in the paper (page number 9) there is an example evaluating the result of the operation `10.1 - 9.93` which results in `0.2` when using a floating point representation of `β = 10` and `p = 3`, it says the result `0.2` has an error of 30 ULPs and every digit in the result is wrong. But I couldn't use the above equation to arrive at 30 ULPs error, the value that I get while calculating the error using above equation is 0.3 ULPs.

This is how I did the calculation:

```
(0.02 - (0.17/(10^1)))*10^(3-1) = 0.3      // 0.17 is the actual difference
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The question strikes me as off-topic for this site. For the example given, the numerical magnitude of 1 ulp = 0.001. The difference between 0.200 and the correct result of 0.170 is 0.030 and therefore 30 ulps.

Comment: @njuffa How did you arrive at the result 1 ulp = 0.001, here the precision is 3, so based on my understanding any number will be of the form d.dd *  β^e

Comment: These are three-digit numbers in the decade [.100, .999]. So the smallest increment is .001. Think of ulp-error as scaled absolute error, with the scale factor changing by a factor of 10 for each decade in decimal arithmetic, and a factor of two for each binade in binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The infinite precision difference of 10.1 - 9.93 is 0.17 .

The machine with β = 10 and p = 3 returned a difference of 0.200.
Notice 3 significant base 10 digits as p = 3 .

The value of the error is |0.17 - 0.2| or 0.03 .

The ULP of 0.200 on this machine is 0.001 .

The correct answer is 0.03/0.001 or 30 ULPs from 0.2 .

---

> the value that I get while calculating the error using above equation is 0.3 ULPs.

Likely as the error is 0.3 ULPs of 10.1 away.  ULP is not a constant for a given machine but a function `ULP(x)` per value.